# How to straighten a motor shaft?

Tags: brushless-motors, repairs

I have a drone with a motor shaft that got slightly bent. I can't buy a replacement bell because they only sell the motor as a whole. Is there any way to bend the motor shaft back into position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this interesting method that can work for larger motor shafts. It involves putting the motor shaft into a drill to spin it. Then something longer is attached to the other side so that it can be bent slightly until it is back in place.

[image: straightening motor shaft]

Here is a video of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=120&v=9bY8JcDpyRY&feature=emb_title

Comment: It might be worth removing the shaft from the bell, so that only the bent section is between the two chucks. As pictured, you could get a new bend inside the bell.

Answer (score 2):

This will be very hard to do.

If the shaft is very bent, I advise ordering a new one, if slightly bent, you can lay it flat on a table and try to straighten it with a hammer or vice.

Comment: A hammer & vice will likely just crush the shaft or deform it. Very difficult indeed.

Comment: @ifconfig yes, that's why it's almost always better to get a replacement

Comment: It's worth noting that motor shafts follow a fairly standard range of sizes, both metric and imperial, so if you can't find a spare shaft for your motor, you can probably find one from a different manufacturer that will fit.